# IntelliJ 11 cannot resolve Play/Scala models without using root package in import statements

Tags: scala, playframework, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I just started working on a project using IntelliJ with Play and Scala plugins that was previously developed in Scala IDE. The project compiles and runs fine, but the IDE is showing a bunch of validation errors throughout controllers because the model symbols cannot be resolved.

Suppose I have a model called User and my controller has import statement:

```
import models.User
```

IntelliJ does not resolve the symbol for User model.  When I try to auto fix the error using "import models.User" action, the IDE creates a second import statement:

```
import _root_.models.Workspace
```

I understand that the root package is used within Scala for absolute package locations, but obviously it is not required in this case and I want the IDE to work properly with the first import statement.

Is there any setting I can change within the IDE or within Play/Scala config to allow the first import statement to work properly? Thanks!

Comment: Also, I set up IDEA project using "play idea" command and Play version is 2.0.3.

Comment: If it compiles without errors, this is a bug in Idea.

Comment: Kim I just contacted IntelliJ support to see if they have any insight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a [known bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-4664), please star/vote to track the progress.

Comment: Thanks you are right.  Also it is worth adding that Play 2.0 is not supported in IntelliJ IDEA 11, so I just switched to [IDEA 12 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12+EAP) and this issue stills occurs.